# Kind of hairy multiline regex needed

Tags: regex, macos, multiline

Am trying to clean up a csv file that has many malformed email addresses, such as this example:

```
"Scarpaci"
"Joseph" <scarp@vt.edu>"
"Adams"
"Robert" <robadams@localnet.com>"
```

which shows two addresses, but with the first and last names on separate lines. I need a regex that will 1) recognize the multiline address, and 2) replace it with the first name, last name and email address all one line, but with the first and last names enclosed in double quotes.

Am using Mac OS, whatever regex engine that has...

Comment: And your attempt looks like what so far? (This is not a free "code on demand" service.)

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. Replace `(?<!>)"\r?\n"` with space, then Replace `(?<=>)"(?=\r?\n")` with  nothing.

Comment: sorry, I did not know where to start using regex on multiple lines...but answer below, using a little perl, provided an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is good for this. Set the record separator to something which matches the end of the records, instead of the default (which is newline):

```
local $/ = '>"';
```

and then you can just read it in "line by line" as normal and clean it up that way. Something like this should help in the loop, using Perl's s modifier so the newline is ok, and x for comments to document it:

```
 /\"([^\"]+)\".+? # first name
  \"([^\"]+)\"\s+ # second name
  <(.+)>\"* # email
 /xs or next;
```

Your output would be something like `"$1 $2" $3`, with the captured groups.

This works fine on MacOS.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

local $/ = '>"';

while (<>) {
    /\"([^\"]+)\".+? # first name
     \"([^\"]+)\"\s+ # second name
     <(.+)>\"* # email
    /xs or next;

    print qq["$1 $2" $3];
}
```

Non-hairy output:

```
$ perl that-script.pl < that-data.txt 
"Scarpaci Joseph" scarp@vt.edu
"Adams Robert" robadams@localnet.com
$
```